# No Method Error for strftime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, strftime

I'm not sure where the error exists.  The same code is working for a collaborator and I can't get this to work!  Let me know what other code need to be shown, I'm not sure where the error is...in the db? Thanks.

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#home
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

...views/shared/_event_detail.html.erb

```
         </span>
       </div>
       <div class="span6 start_date">
         <%=event.start_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') %>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row-fluid">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`event.start_date` is nil.  You're trying to call `strftime` on an instance of NilClass.  You want the below which will "try" and call the method, but will fail silently if the method isn't available (ie. if event.start_date is nil).

```
     <%=event.start_date.try(:strftime, '%B %d, %Y') %>
```